# How to use 'on time' as an adjective

Tags: synonyms

I would like to say " By seeing my punctuality you can see how desperate I am " I'm not sure if punctuality is the right word here ,If not any alternatives?

Comment: Your question is not clear. "Punctuality" is a noun, "on time" is a prepositional phrase, and you want an adjective?

Comment: The proposed utterance wouldn't be idiomatic without radical revision. You might consider something like *The fact that I'm so punctual shows you how desperate I am*. But to be honest, being "punctual, on time" is usually something you either do or don't do. ***Not*** being punctual might be seen as evidence that you don't care (but more likely the train was late or your car broke down anyway). But actually *being* punctual is no more than might be expected. Perhaps by "punctual" you mean *arriving **long before** the appointed time.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> I'm so desperate I actually showed up on time!

Unless you have a context saying otherwise, people are generally expected to be on time to things like jobs and meetings, so if you don't normally show up on time, *actually* is needed to emphasize that you are doing something out of the ordinary.

Or this if you want to stay close to the form of your sentence:

> By the fact that I'm actually on time, you can see how desperate I am.

Comment: So there is no adjective for the trait of being on time ? But your answer works for me too .

Answer (score 0):

You can use “timely”. His timely appearance meant the party could start.